# Json Hash map view in jsp

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring

I need a solution to my problem, with my type Json I return `{"1":"Position1","2":"Position2"}` but I need `[{"id":1,"name":Position1},{"id":2,"name":Position2}]`

it is my method controller:

```
@GET
@RequestMapping(value = "/getPositiontMapByDepartmentId/{departmentId}")
@ResponseBody
public String getPositiontMapByDepartmentId(Employee employee, Model model,
                                     @PathVariable("departmentId") int departmentId) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<Position> positionListById = positionService.findAllPositionsByDepartmentId(departmentId);
    Map<Integer, String> positiontMapByDepartmentId = preparePositionMapByDepartmentId(departmentId);
    positionListById.toArray();
    return gson.toJson(positiontMapByDepartmentId);
}
public Map<Integer, String> preparePositionMapByDepartmentId(int departmentId) {
    Map<Integer, String> positiontMapByDepartmentId = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    List<Position> positionListById = positionService.findAllPositionsByDepartmentId(departmentId);
    for( Position position : positionListById){
        positiontMapByDepartmentId.put(position.getId(),position.getName());
    }
    return positiontMapByDepartmentId;
}
```

My jsp and Java Script

```js
$(document).ready(
        function() {

            $('#departmentSelect').on("change", function () {
                var departmentId = $("#departmentSelect option:selected").val();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "/admin/getPositiontMapByDepartmentId/"+departmentId,
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert(result);
                            var result = JSON.parse(result);
                            var position = "";
                            for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
                               position+= '<option value="' + result[i].id + '">' + result[i].name +'</option>';
                            }
                            $('#positionSelect').html(position);
                        }
                    });
            });
        });
```

when I get `{"1":"Position1","2":"Position2"}` my JS can improve select to html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getPositiontMapByDepartmentId doesn't return an array , it returns a map. Hence to get an array, convert the map into a set and then call toArray()

Use the following return value in the method.

```
return gson.toJson(positiontMapByDepartmentId.entrySet().toArray());
```

Comment: thx it work !!!